# popbackstack() not working

Tags: android, fragment-backstack

In order for my tabs to retain the information entered in it previously (like in EditText), I'm storing the fragments in backstack and trying to pop it from the backstack when user switches tabs and comes back to the previous one.

But the 'popBackStack()' method doesn't seem to work. This is my code snippet:

```
fragment = null;

        fragment = Tab1.newInstance(1,categoryName.get(0));

        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack("tab1");
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
        tabListBuffer.add(tabLayout.getTabAt(0)); //Add the first tab to arrayList


// perform setOnTabSelectedListener event on TabLayout
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                tabListBuffer.add(tab);
                int count=0;
                int temp=0;

                for (int i = 0; i < tabListBuffer.size(); i++) {
                    if (tabListBuffer.get(i) == tab) {
                        temp=i+1;


                        count++;


                    }
                    final int str = temp;
                    if (count>=2)
                    tabRepeatPos=str;
                }


// get the current selected tab's position and replace the fragment accordingly
                fragment = Tab1.newInstance(tab.getPosition(), categoryName.get(tab.getPosition()));
                String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
                fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                boolean fragmentPopped = fm.popBackStackImmediate();

                ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);

                ft.addToBackStack("tab" + tab.getPosition());

                if (fragmentPopped) {
                    fm.popBackStack("tab"+tabRepeatPos, 0);
                    fm.executePendingTransactions();
                }

                ft.commit();
                }
```

What is wrong with my code? Did I place the 'popBackStack()' method at a wrong place?

Please, please help!

Answer (score 0):

When add and remove a fragment to the stack try the other method with TAGs.
And then pop by TAG. It should work

Comment: How exactly should I use TAGS?

Comment: I think my my fragment is being destroyed when a new instance of it is created. So popping from backstack recreates the earlier fragment.